# Box login - how do develop opn both localhost and in production?

Tags: ibm-cloud, box, oauth-2.0

I have:

- a Node.js app that uses the Box Content API, and...
- a Box app, just so I can register an Oauth2 client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri with my Box repo.

My current redirect_uri is "http:/localhost:3000".  The app works fine if I run locally,  It fails miserably if I deploy to Bluemix (e.g. "https://myapp.mybluemix.net").

I believe you can register multiple redirect_uris for a single Oauth2 client_id/client_secret in Facebook and Google, But I can't see any workaround in Box.  Except to create a second app...

These posts are similar, but I don't need to authenticate *TO* a separate OAuth2 server ... I just need to authenticate *FROM* two different *ENVIRONMENTS* (my Node app locally, vs. the same Node app on Bluemix).

- [Facebook login - how to develop on both localhost and in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912485/facebook-login-how-to-develop-on-both-localhost-and-in-production)
- [Using OAuth for both development and production environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233495/using-oauth-for-both-development-and-production-environments)

Is there any way that I can register multiple redirect_uris for the *same* Box app?

### Addendum

1. Following from the reply from Murtza Manzur:

   > Box does not support multiple domain redirect URIs. To use different domains (localhost and mybluemix.net), you would have to create a separate app for each domain.
2. This means I need two Box apps, and I need to configure my Bluemix/Node app to use one or the other.
3. Here is an excellent discussion about how to do that efficiently and securely in Bluemix:

   - [Keeping secrets – how your cloud application should access credentials and other private data, Patrick Mueller](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/14/keeping-secrets-cloud-application-access-credentials-private-data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box does not support multiple domain redirect URIs. To use different domains (localhost and mybluemix.net), you would have to create a separate app for each domain.