# Facebook sign in for local app error

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm currently developing an application which requires that the user be able to sign in with his/her Facebook account. I'm using the Facebook SDK, but when I log in, I get the following error:

> De opgegeven URL wordt niet toegestaan door de configuratie van de applicatie.:
>
> One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.wing error:

Any idea's how to solve this problem?

Comment: please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally/10893495#10893495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Facebook App Settings page, make sure you have correctly filled out your website's URL so Facebook knows where you application is hosted. Also, make sure your domain is entered into the "App Domains" field (e.g. `example.com`, without the http)

Comment: YES! a small typing mistake can cause lots of trouble!

thanks mate, cheers!