# How can I test my facebook app with localhost

Tags: facebook

Now I'm trying to use the sample code in facebook PHP SDK.

Though I can use localhost to view my web on Google Chrome broser,when I fill the URL

(I use APPSERV as my server)

localhost in the "Secure Canvas URL" blank, it always says server connection denied.

(I'm not sure if the message in English is correct.It shows "伺服器拒絕連線"on my broswer)

Thanks for everyone who answers my question.

Comment: Just disable "secure browsing" to force facebook to use a "default" http-connection:

Comment: It's also possible that you did not enable HTTPS connection to your server, check your settings.

Comment: @Blauesocke:Do you mean to adjsut the broswer settings or facebook app settings?

Comment: @kayson :I use APPSERV as my server,so do you mean to check the settings of APPSERV?
thanks

Comment: @kayson Your facebook-account-settings. When your test with a local server (e.g. localhost) there is (in the most cases) no valid https certificate, so if you just fallback to http everything should work as preferred (Disable secure browsing here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security)

Comment: @Blauesocke In default situation,I have disabled secure browsing,besides when I tried to enable it,I can't disable it anymore.
The "edit" tag has disappeared

Comment: you have to get a self-signed certificate on your server and configure it to accept HTTPS requests (e.g. open port 443), depending on your exact config. You can find the detailed steps elsewhere. by the way "伺服器拒絕連線" translates to "server rejected connection" in English; I can read Chinese.

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally?rq=1 to get an idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can not develop your facebook app on your localhost without SSL anymore.

Facebook made Secure Browsing default and no way to undo it.

So if you want to test your own app on localhost you have to self signed your app.

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/secure-browsing-by-default/10151590414803920