# Facebook App localhost not working

Tags: php, facebook, localhost

I was trying to build a website with php that will have faceboo login system. But I am now working in localhost. So I have followed tutorials for that and like they have stated i have created a virtual host in my pc "tamztest.com" and then i have set the url in my facebook application settnigs like this

http://tamztest.com/

But still i am getting this error "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5133075/2518525)

Comment: Please check this link on [How to Test Facebook Connect Locally(Stackoverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to create a virtual path you can just provide URL like **http://localhost/yourproject/login.php/** and use provided App Key and Secret Key.