# I can not get the spring.io Facebook Guides to work

Tags: spring-social-facebook

We are foloowing the spring.io guides:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/register-facebook-app/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

When we start the server and then click the "Connect to Facebook" button we get an error from Facebook that we do have an redirect url that is not the same as the server asking for permissins.
We use a localhost and have tried to remove the reredirect url in the Facebook app but that is required by Facebook. 
But in the example, register-faecbook-app at the end of the page I see that it states "Website URL:    null" but we can no set that since that field is reuired.

Any suggestions about how to proceed. We would like to be able to run locally during development.

I have made connectins to Facebook with other solutions than spring.io and have never been abli to run with localhost as in these two exmples and it would be a very good possibility since it makes development much easier.

Comment: I found this at another place at stackoverflow:

1. Go to your app and Select Settings -> Advanced Tab

2. Get your public IP (google will tell you if you google "Whats My IP")

3. Add your public IP to the Server IP Whitelist and click Save Changes at the bottom

And it worked. Might be that it should be added to the guides.

The complete discussion is at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this at another solution:

1. Go to your app and Select Settings -> Advanced Tab
2. Get your public IP (google will tell you if you google "Whats My IP")
3. Add your public IP to the Server IP Whitelist and click Save Changes at the bottom And it worked. Might be that it should be  to the guides.