# fB share button is not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

This is the code i am using to display the Share button

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://youtube.com" data-layout="button_count"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the share button is not showing
any ideas?

Comment: Where have you placed the JS?  It should be straight after the opening `<body>` tag.  Also, you have no App ID.

Comment: ok let me show the whole code to you

Comment: Are you trying to use this on your local machine?  What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  file://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally) might help you - otherwise, you need to test it on live site.