# Facebook login showing error when try to test on the localhost

Tags: php, django, facebook, oauth

I am trying to integrate facebook login for my test website. I am hosting my website on my local machine at `http:///127.0.0.1:8000`. My redirect url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`. But when I try to login from my facebook account (from the same machine) it throws:
 `"URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."` 
and  `"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."`
Under the Basic settings *App Domains* contain `127.0.0.1:8000` and *Site URL* is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` ( I have also tried without the trailing '/'). Under *Advanced Settings* `Server IP whitelist` has `127.0.0.1` and `Valid Oauth redirect URIs` is`http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`.  And under *Client OAuth Settings*  everything is set to `Yes`.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Is it because I am hosting my website on my local host ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 'Test app' on facebook. you should have a look at this related answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131470/2405066

Comment: As I mentioned in my question Site URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/. I have also tried http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @user3708999 you should read the answer and your comment again

Comment: Thanks ! I did not see the last answer

Comment: No. I have tried all possible options. At last tried changing the host file to set my.web.com at 127.0.0.1 Still did not work.

Comment: Please check here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally/33131470#33131470