# URI blocked while login with Facebook in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs. The above error shown in while i press login with
>   facebook
>
> in valid outh http://www.example.com/the78/login-facebook.php
>
> and all the process in my side is handle on the same url.

```
<?php

require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'fbconfig.php';
require 'functions.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }






    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        die('we are  in ');
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

        $username = $user_profile['name'];
             $uid = $user_profile['id'];
         $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
           echo ("<script>location.href='users/home.php'</script>");
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
   // header("Location: " . $login_url);
    echo ("<script>location.href='$login_url'</script>");
}
?>

This is the facebook url which shows error

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1575902869377664&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fthe78%2Flogin-facebook.php&state=f80b87f59baa9ca6ec69733e55b227f0&scope=email
```

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally/33131470#33131470

Comment: i did that things but still same issue