# How to test Facebook login with localhost

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, django-allauth

I'm using Django, and want to make Facebook login with `django-allauth`.

I made Facebook login with few time, and tested it with localhost.

But I found out that FB login require `https` after 2018 march, so when I login fb in local runserver, it gives error like `Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://`.

Is there any way to test fb login in localhost?

Comment: you might want to look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally)

Comment: Thanks, but it's about the url. I'm talking about http/https. FB restricts only https now, but it's impossible in localhost right? (even if I change the localhost url name)

Comment: no its not possible now..but you can try  https://ngrok.com/. only problem here is the domain gets changed every time you reconnect. unless you get a premium account

Comment: Oh thanks! It's pretty useful for dev environment. thankyou!

Comment: All you need to do, is set up your localhost for HTTPS. You can use a self-signed certificate - all the relevant stuff regarding login happens inside your browser, so it doesn’t have to be a fully “valid” setup, you’ll just have to make your browser accept the certificate, resp click through the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a real subdomain like `dev.yourdomain.com` and point its DNS to `127.0.0.1` (or can use `lvh.me` domain since it also point to 127.0.0.1 - but if you trust them all the time)

Then you need a layer to handle `HTTPS` in local for `https://dev.yourdomain.com`. I recommend https://caddyserver.com/

With a very simple config like this then Caddy can use its self-signed SSL cert (checkout Caddy docs to get the detail)

```
dev.yourdomain.com:443 {
    tls self_signed
    proxy / localhost:8080
}
```

Then you can open `https://dev.yourdomain.com` in some browsers like Firefox, Safari, Brave, etc. (I think Chrome blocked self-signed SSL site by default)

**UPDATE** I create a note here with more detail

https://gist.github.com/ralavay/5d74d35859f87d22c74984488f20186c