# Cant test FB SDK login locally even though I have set my domain and site URL (app is test mode)

Tags: facebook, authentication, https, sdk

I am developing a web app with Facebook integration and I can't figure out why I can't test the login function locally. I have looked through the answers here ([How to Test Facebook Connect Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459728/how-to-test-facebook-connect-locally)) and have tried to follow the steps of having the app in test mode, setting the site URL and the domain.

Based on FBs documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/
I should be able to use http for localhost development, but I get the error

`The method FB.api can no longer be called from http pages. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/`

and can't log in. Below are pictures of my app settings (including an indication it is an app in 'test mode').
[image: Site URl]

[image: App Settings]
[image: Test Mode]

Answer (score 0):

So this is really only a half answer, but it seemed easier for me to just force https for my local development using mkcert (https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert). After creating local certs I updated my site URL to say `https://localhost:8080` and I am able to log in without issue.